# sql more complicated querying measurements

Tags: sql

I have two tables (sql server), as shown below:

```
locations 
   id           cubicfeet   order
-------------------------------------
   1            5             1    
   2            10            1
   3            6             1

items 
   id           cubic feet    order
--------------------------------------
   1            6               1
   2            6               1
   3            6               1
```

I need a query to tell me if all the items will fit into all the locations (for a given order).  If all items will not fit into 1 or all locations then I need to create a new location for that given order - and then move any items that DID fit into the locations before to the new location (as many as fit).  The new location will only be given a certain amount of cubic feet also - say 17. In this example, sum won't work because all 3 records are 6 so the sum is 18, which is less than the sum of 5,10,6, but the location with volume 5 can't fit any of the items since they are all volume 6 cubic feet.

Comment: Edit your question and show the data in the tables using a tabular format -- one line per row in the table.  Hint:  four spaces at the beginning of each row help with formatting.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read the guidelines for asking a good question on the site, found here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Your question should include any code that you've tried as well as clear examples of what you're trying to do.

Comment: You also need to tell us which DBMS you are using. Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: `select id from locations where cubicfeet < some (select cubicfeet from items)` Zero results means "Yes".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the only way I think I can do it is creating temp tables in my sp and using a while loop to go through them and update the locations 1 at a time to see if it still fits more...